# ViewPager with ExoPlayer. Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, exoplayer

There is a problem. I need to implement video playback as in YouTube Shorts, SnapChat and TikTok. Implemented page flipping with ViewPager from accompanist, but there is a problem, all ViewPager videos are playing. I need help in implementing playback of only the videos that are on the screen.

My implementation of the player:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalPagerApi::class)
@Composable
@androidx.annotation.OptIn(androidx.media3.common.util.UnstableApi::class)
fun VideoPlayer(
    url: String,
) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val uri = Uri.parse(url)

    val exoPlayer = remember {
        ExoPlayer.Builder(context)
            .build().apply {
                val defaultDataSourceFactory = DefaultDataSource.Factory(context)
                val dataSourceFactory: DataSource.Factory = DefaultDataSource.Factory(
                    context,
                    defaultDataSourceFactory
                )
                val source = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                    .createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri(uri))

                setMediaSource(source)
                prepare()
            }
    }

    exoPlayer.playWhenReady = true
    exoPlayer.videoScalingMode = C.VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT_WITH_CROPPING
    exoPlayer.repeatMode = Player.REPEAT_MODE_ONE


    AndroidView(modifier = Modifier.clickable {
        if (exoPlayer.isPlaying) {
            exoPlayer.pause()
        } else {
            exoPlayer.play()
        }

    }, factory = {
        PlayerView(context).apply {
            hideController()
            useController = false
            resizeMode = AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_ZOOM

            player = exoPlayer
            layoutParams = FrameLayout.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT)
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try it like this

```
val pagerState = rememberPagerState(pageCount)
ViewPager(state = pagerState) { page ->
    VideoPlayer(url, playWhenReady = page == pagerState.currentPage
}
```

and in VideoPlayer:

```
VideoPlayer(url: String, playWhenReady: Boolean) {
    ...
    exoPlayer.playWhenReady = playWhenReady
}
```